# PHP Create a new Multidimensional Array by combining elements from an existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a new multidemensional array by combining the values from an array created by submitting a form. I am not sure what is the most efficient way to accomplish this.

**Starting array:**

```
[Student_Data] => Array
(
[mother-lastname] => Trucker
[mother-firstname] => Cindy
[father-lastname] => Power
[father-firstname] => Bob
[child_0-lastname] => Powers
[child_0-firstname] => mike
[add_sib1] => Array
(
[0] => Yes
)
[child_1-lastname] => Power
[child_1-firstname] => Anne
[add_sib2] => Array
(
[0] => Yes
)
[child_2-lastname] => Power
[child_2-firstname] => Ted
[alt-contact-lastname] => Smith
[alt-contact-firstname] => Tom
[alt-contact-number] => 777-7777
)
```

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

```
[SubmissionData] => Array
(
  [student] => Array
    (
    [mother-lastname] => Trucker
    [mother-firstname] => Cindy
    [father-lastname] => Power
    [father-firstname] => Bob
    [child_0-lastname] => Powers
    [child_0-firstname] => mike
    [alt-contact-lastname] => Smith
    [alt-contact-firstname] => Tom
    [alt-contact-number] => 777-7777
    ),
  [student] => Array
  (
    [mother-lastname] => Trucker
    [mother-firstname] => Cindy
    [father-lastname] => Power
    [father-firstname] => Bob
    [child_1-lastname] => Power
    [child_1-firstname] => Anne
    [alt-contact-lastname] => Smith
    [alt-contact-firstname] => Tom
    [alt-contact-number] => 777-7777
  ),
  [student] => Array
  (
    [mother-lastname] => Trucker
    [mother-firstname] => Cindy
    [father-lastname] => Power
    [father-firstname] => Bob
    [child_2-lastname] => Power
    [child_2-firstname] => Ted
    [alt-contact-lastname] => Smith
    [alt-contact-firstname] => Tom
    [alt-contact-number] => 777-7777
  )
)
```

Background: So I know I want to check if add_sib1 and add_sib2 are True first so I know how many student arrays will be inside of submissionData array. Each nested array has a lot of the same data with the exception of the child names and last-names.

Question: Can this be done via loops or do I need to statically build the arrays and then push them into submissionData?

Comment: I don't understand your result. It has keys but no values.

Comment: Where does `alt-contact-phone` come from in the result?

Comment: It seems obvious that you should use a loop.

Comment: Use a `while` loop that increments an index `$i`, and stops when `$_POST["child_{$i}-lastname"]` doesn't exist. Then create a new element of the result array containing all the common fields and the child-specific fields.

Comment: @Barmar that is exactly how I wanted to approach it thanks for the recommendation. If you want to submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's not detailed enough for an answer, it was just a hint to get you going.

Comment: Thats all I needed. If someone hasn't answered it by the time I get it working I will post the results. Thanks again.